# parsing json file in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, io

Have a file in plaintext that looks as follows:

```
{
   "user1":[int1, int2...intX], 
   "user2":[int1, int2...intX], 
    ... 
   "userX":[int1, int2...intX]
}
```

I want to be able to cycle through all users and their corresponding lists of integers; what's the best way to load and parse through this object?

Eventually I want to do something like:

```
for user, intlist in [FILE]:
    for item in intlist:
        [perform some function on each int]
```

though I'm not sure the right way to set up the IO and then leveraging the json library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python JSON tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759634/python-json-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load the file with `json.load()`:

```
import json

with open('yourfile') as infile:
    for user, intlist in json.load(infile).iteritems():
        for item in intlist:
```

Your JSON contains a dictionary top-level object, so the above code calls `.iteritems()` to loop over each key-value combo in that object.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for user, intlist in data.items():
    for item in intlist:
        do_your_stuff(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the above answers, you may also try the package 'simplejson' which supports a bit more python objects than the plain 'json'